# Need xml corrections

Tags: jquery, xml

I have a drop down menu with xml. When accessing the URL with www. the drop down & xml file  works perfectly. If you access the site without the www. the xml file is not found. How do I write the xml file so it works for both with www. and without www.?

```
 <Menu1               txt="COMMERCIAL GRILLS" Link="http://bigjohngrills.com" browser="_self">
<Submenu    txt="Gas Grills"    Link="Gas.html"          browser="_self"/>
<Submenu    txt="Towable Gas Grills"                  Link="GasTowable.html"         browser="_self"/>
<Submenu    txt="Charcoal Grills"                 Link="CharGrills.html"                    browser="_self"/>
<Submenu    txt="Towable Charcoal Grills"         Link="CharTow.html"                    browser="_self"/>
<Submenu    txt="Portable Griddles"                   Link="Griddles.html"                    browser="_self"/>
<Submenu    txt="Steam Tables"                Link="Steam.html"                    browser="_self"/>
<Submenu    txt="Utility Stoves"                  Link="UtilPots.html"                    browser="_self"/>
<Submenu    txt="Pots & Woks"                 Link="PotWok.html"                    browser="_self"/>
<Submenu    txt="Smokers"                 Link="Smokers.html"                    browser="_self"/>
<Submenu    txt="Ovens & Ranges"                  Link="OvRange.html"                    browser="_self"/>
<Submenu    txt="Counter Top Units"                   Link="Countertop.html"                    browser="_self"/>
 </Menu1>

 <Menu2               txt="RESIDENTIAL GRILLS"  Link="ResidentMob.html" browser="_self">
<Submenu    txt="Built-In Grills"                Link="LM.html"         browser="_self"/>
<Submenu    txt="Mobile Residential Gas Grills"              Link="ResidentMob.html"        browser="_self"/>
<Submenu    txt="Vermont Islands"                Link="Vermont.html"        browser="_self"/>
<Submenu    txt="Residential Smokers"                Link="ResSmokers.html"         browser="_self"/>
 </Menu2>

 <Menu3               txt="ORDERING INFO"   Link="Ordering.html" browser="_self">  
<Submenu    txt="3 Ways to Order"   Link="Ordering.html"        browser="_self"/>
<Submenu    txt="Shipping Info"     Link="Shipping.html"        browser="_self"/>
<Submenu    txt="Receipt of Order"      Link="Receipt.html"         browser="_self"/>
<Submenu    txt="Warranty Info"     Link="Warranty.html"        browser="_self"/>
<Submenu    txt="Returns"   Link="Returns.html"         browser="_self"/>                   
 </Menu3>

 <Menu4               txt="REPLACEMENT PARTS"     Link="Replacement.html" browser="_self" >
<Submenu    txt="Charcoal Grills"   Link="PartsChargrill.html"      browser="_self"/>
<Submenu    txt="Charcoal Rotisseries"      Link="8BPartsrotis.html"        browser="_self"/>
<Submenu    txt="Gas Grills"    Link="8CPartsGas.html"      browser="_self"/>
<Submenu    txt="210 Series Grills"     Link="8K210Parts.html"      browser="_self"/>
<Submenu    txt="Gas Griddles"      Link="8DPartsGrid.html"         browser="_self"/>
<Submenu    txt="Big 60"            Link="8EParts60.html"           browser="_self"/>
<Submenu    txt="Pot Cookers"           Link="8J-PartsPotCookers.html"          browser="_self"/>
<Submenu    txt="Steam Tables"      Link="8FPartssteam.html"        browser="_self"/>
<Submenu    txt="EZ Way Roaster/Smoker"     Link="8GPartsez.html"       browser="_self"/>
<Submenu    txt="Trail Boss Towables"   Link="8HPartsTrailBoss.html"        browser="_self"/>
 </Menu4>

 <Menu5               txt="HOW TO......."   Link="HowTo.html" browser="_self"           >
<Submenu    txt="How To .. Info"    Link="HowTo.html"       browser="_self"/>
<Submenu    txt="Assemble & Operate Info"   Link="Assembly-2.html"      browser="_self"/>
 </Menu5>

 <Menu6               txt="CORPORATE INFO"                Link="WeAre.html"         browser="_self">
<Submenu    txt="Who We Are"    Link="WeAre.html"       browser="_self"/>
<Submenu    txt="Request a Catalog"     Link="CatRequest.html"      browser="_self"/>
<Submenu    txt="Contact Us"    Link="CorpInfo.html"        browser="_self"/>
<Submenu    txt="Trade Associations"    Link="assoc.html"       browser="_self"/>
<Submenu    txt="Showroom Directions"   Link="Showroom.html"        browser="_self"/>
 </Menu6>

 <Menu7               txt="THE PIG PEN"               Link="PigPen.html"        browser="_self">
<Submenu    txt="Pig Pen"   Link="PigPen.html"      browser="_self"/>
<Submenu    txt="Pig Roasters"      Link="EZ.html"      browser="_self"/>
<Submenu    txt="Charcoal Rotisseries"      Link="CharRotis.html"       browser="_self"/>
<Submenu    txt="Towable Rotisseries"   Link="SDR.html"         browser="_self"/>
<Submenu    txt="HOW TO Roast a Pig"    Link="HTRoastPig.html"      browser="_self"/>
<Submenu    txt="Recipes"   Link="http://www.cooks.com/rec/search/0,1-0,roast_pig,FF.html.html"         browser="_self"/>
 </Menu7>

 <Menu6      X_sub="330"       txt="EMAIL US"      Link="mailto:BJGrills@aol.com"                 browser="_self">
 </Menu6>
```

Comment: Could you show what code you have?

Comment: Your question is more about [naked domains](https://www.google.com/search?q=naked%20domains) than XML or JQuery.

Comment: If you're making an AJAX request to retrieve the XML, you need to ensure the current domain and the requested domain are exactly the same. You may encounter a problem like the above if you use absolute URLs instead of relative. This is just a hunch though, to diagnose the problem properly we need to see your code that builds the menu from the XML.